# How do I take Win 7 off a dual boot mini

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall

---

I have an HP mini with dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Win 7. I am VERY green at Linux and would like to take the Win 7 off and have a Linux only mini. No CD drive so it would have to be done with a jump drive or a USB CD drive.

Comment: How much RAM, HDD storage capacity, what **HP Mini** series/model? *I've owned 5 of these Minis, and currently have a **210-4000** with 2GB RAM and 320GB running Ubuntu **12.04.2** LTS.*

Comment: Question: Is this a dual boot using GRUB or did you use Wubi?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) tool. It will remove Windows and update your GRUB entries. Then you can use the free space the way you wish (by putting data in it, or resizing the Ubuntu partitions via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted)).

[image]